# SyntaxError: Unexpected token n in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHtt…, text: "nn@gmail.com"

Tags: json, angular, unexpected-token

I am using angular 7 so I am trying to get the JSON objects from the backend. It may be due the parsing of JSON objects. I am new to angualar, so please help

```
login(email:String, password:String) {
return this.http.get<any>(`${this.baseUrl}/${email}/${password}`)
    .map(user =>  {

        if (user &&user.token) {

            localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));

        }else{

        }
      return user;

    });

}
}
```

Comment: Error suggests you are not receiving JSON. So what are you receiving?

Comment: Could you `console.log` the `user` result and provide us what is logged?

Comment: My suspicion is that you are receiving text, but you need to confirm that from your network tab. Then check https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data

Comment: Hi , I am recieving plain text instead of JSON. Any suggesting on how to get JSON

Comment: @RidickKhoza Then check the link I shared, you can create an object yourself based on the plain text you are receiving.